# ¿Warning al subir mi proyecto : Cannot modify header information?

Tags: php, html

Por ahora sé que se produce cuando hay espacios en blanco antes de `<?php` o después de las etiquetas de cierre, ya he resuelto esto en varios archivos pero no puedo encontrar el error en este.

Esta es mi función para validar al usuario:

```
function usuarioE($id_usuario)
{
    global $conexion;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios1 where usuarios1.id =? limit 1";
    $usuario = getRegistroSimple($sql, 'i', [$id_usuario]);
    if (!empty($usuario))
    {
        //Poner usuario logueado en el array de sesión
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
        $rolesSql = "SELECT roles.nombre FROM roles JOIN roles_usuario on roles.id = roles_usuario.roles_id WHERE roles_usuario.usuario_id=?";
        $rolesUsuario = getMultRegistros($rolesSql, 'i', [$usuario['id']]);

        if (!empty($usuario))//Si no existe error con el usuario, se manda junto con el array de sesión, los roles que pertenecen al mismo.
        {
            header('location: '.URL_BASE.'admin/cursos/cursosList.php');
            $_SESSION['rolesUsuario'] = $rolesUsuario;
            $_SESSION['welcome'] = "Bienvenido";
            exit();
        }

        else {
            $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "Intenta de nuevo";
        }

        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Luego el error lo marca en la **línea 5** del archivo *admin/cursos/cursosList.php*. Mis 10 primeras líneas de ese archivo son las siguientes:

```
<?php include('../../conexion.php'); ?>
<?php include('../../middleware2.php'); ?>
<?php include('cursosLogic.php') ?>
<?php include(RUTA_FN); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html><!--ESTA ES LA LÍNEA 5 -->
<html lang="es">
    <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CURSOS</title>
```

Acá en este otro archivo se verifica la función *usuarioE*:

```
    //Login de Usuarios

if(isset($_POST['login_btn']))
{   //Valida valores del formulario
    //$errores = validarUsuario($_POST, ['login_btn']);
    $correo     = $_POST['correo'];
    $contrasena = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios1 WHERE nombre=? OR correo=? LIMIT 1";
    $usuario = getRegistroSimple($sql, 'ss', [$correo, $correo]);

        if (!empty($usuario)) //Si se encontró el correo(usuario)
        {   
            if (password_verify($contrasena, $usuario['contrasena'])) 
            {
                usuarioE($usuario['id']);
            }
            else //Si no coincide 
            {
                $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "Correo o contraseña incorrecto";

                echo mysqli_errno($conexion) . ": " . mysqli_error($conexion). "\n";
            }
        }
            else 
            {//Si el usuario no se encuentra
                $_SESSION['error_msg'] = "El usuario no está registrado";
            }
}
```

?>

Comment: ¿En qué archivo está la función `usuarioE`?

Comment: El archivo se llama funciones.php y en el archivo de LoginVal.php valida la función.

Comment: Revisa el orden en que se incluyen tus archivos. En `usuarioE` tú tienes esto: `header('location: '.URL_BASE.'admin/cursos/cursosList.php');` pues **cuando usas `header` no puede salir nada por pantalla antes de eso, así sea un espacio en blanco**. El *`Cannot modify header information`*  significa que ya sacaste algo por pantalla antes de ese código, y por tanto los encabezados no pueden modificarse. Es cuestión de organizar el orden en que incluyes tus archivos.

Comment: Vale, revisaré bien ese aspecto, gracias.